# Why is \blitza displayed as a psi in beamer?

Tags: beamer, symbols

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{ulsy}

\begin{document}
    \frame{
        \begin{align*}
            \blitza
        \end{align*}
    }
\end{document}
```

Why is the `\blitza` symbol displayed as a *psi*?

Comment: Not really an answer, but it's not *psi* outside math mode. So perhaps you should write `\text{\blitza}`.

Comment: @KevinC: That works!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I need a contradiction symbol for a proof. There's a lot of discussing about an official symbol for this (see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160039/contradiction-any-symbol-for), but I have the habit to use a "lightning". I don't get any errors after compiling.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This particular symbol (lightning with an arrow tip) seems pretty scalable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It's a Type1 font.

Comment: @KevinC sorry so it is availabel as type1: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/ulsy/ I'll delete some of my earlier comments

Comment: @KevinC That's the correct answer: the definition of `\blitza` is `{\usefont{U}{ulsy}{m}{n}\symbol{'012}}` and `\usefont` does nothing in math mode, so only `\symbol{'012}` is performed, which corresponds to a Psi.

Comment: @egreg: Believe it or not, I was waiting for *you* to give the correct explanation `:)` Your comment should be made an answer, since the OP asked for a *why* instead of a *how*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `\blitza` in `ulsy.sty` is

```
\newcommand{\blitza}{{\usefont{U}{ulsy}{m}{n}\symbol{'011}}}
```

which clearly means it's a symbol just for text mode.

In math mode `\usefont` does nothing at all, so what is executed is equivalent to `{\symbol{'011}}` which is just the same as

```
{\char'011\relax}
```

and the rules of TeX say that this will be the symbol in octal position `'011` of  mathgroup zero font, which is an uppercase Psi.

You can use it in math mode if you redefine it with `\text`:

```
\renewcommand{\blitza}{\text{\usefont{U}{ulsy}{m}{n}\symbol{'011}}}
```

Answer (score 8):

the wasy fonts are more likely to be installed in most installations of Tex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{wasysym}


\begin{document}
    \frame{
        \begin{align*}
            [\text{\lightning}]
        \end{align*}
    }
\end{document}
```

Incidentally I found that just by drawing the character:

[image]

Comment: Also an upvote for your beautiful drawing! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different sources for a lightning character, depending on what is installed on your system.

In addition to

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\lightning
```

, there is also my favorite:

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
$\lightning$
```

(this one is for mathmode)

and

```
\usepackage{marvosym}
\Lightning
```

Found that all three came up in Detexify
[image]