# The lightning symbol in an equation environment

Tags: symbols

I tried to use the lightning symbol but when I use it together with equations it becomes an ''E'' Why is that?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} %margin
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{ marvosym }


\begin{document}
\Lightning
but when used in an equation environment it becomes ''E''
\begin{equation}
\Lambda\gamma \Lightning
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

the output
[image]

What can be done to use \Lightning in equations? Thank you

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80053 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148757

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To instruct LaTeX to treat `\Lightning` as a text-mode rather than as a math-mode macro, you could type either

```
\mbox{\Lightning}
```

or (since you're already loading the `amsmath` package)

```
\text{\Lightning}
```

for all math-mode occurrences of this macro.

---

*Addendum*: As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, a key issue (bug?) is that the file `marvosym.sty` provides the instruction

```
\newcommand{\mvchr}[1]{{\mvs\char#1}}
```

This macro assumes (implicitly) that the symbols of the `marvosym` package will only ever be used in text mode. By redefining this macro via

```
\renewcommand{\mvchr}[1]{\mbox{\mvs\symbol{#1}}}
```

in the preamble (*after* loading the `marvosym` package, of course), the behavior of this macro is modified globally and it's no longer necessary to encase any of the many individual macros of the `marvosym` package in `\mbox` wrappers.

Comment: A different strategy could be `\renewcommand{\mvchr}[1]{\mbox{\mvs\symbol{#1}}}` (or `\text` instead of `\mbox` with `amsmath`). This is what `\mvchr` should do to begin with.

Comment: The best way to do this is `\textnormal{\Lightning}`, or possibly `\textup{\Lightning}` if you want a bold version to show in headers. If you use `\text` while the surrounding text is an italicized theorem statement, it will also be italicized. If you use `\mbox`, the symbol won’t scale in a superscript or subscript.

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks. The `\Lightning` macro of the `marvosym` package doesn't appear to possess an italic or bold variant, let alone bold-italic, sans-serif, or small-caps variants. Hence, the recommendation to replace `\text` with either `\textnormal` or `\textup` doesn't affect the output of `\Lightning`. Am I maybe missing something?

Comment: @Mico I think you’re right about `marvosym`, but if the package ever gets updated with more font faces, or the asker ever copies this code into a different document, it’d break unexpectedly.

Comment: @Davislor - Martin Vogel last updated the `marvosym` package more than nine years ago. Should he update his package along the lines you envisage, I would fervently hope that he'd have the good sense to incorporate the required safeguards into the package code. Knock on wood.

Answer (score 24):

Just in order to show some more ways to get a lightning symbol (the answer to your problem has been given in Micos answer and in the referenced questions in my comment):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\let\marvosymLightning\Lightning
\usepackage{wasysym}
\let\wasysymLightning\lightning
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\let\stmaryrdLightning\lightning
\usepackage{ulsy}
\let\ulsyLightning\blitza
% just for the last two lines:
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\[\text{\marvosymLightning}\text{\wasysymLightning}\stmaryrdLightning\text{\ulsyLightning}\]
% Lua- or XeLaTeX needed for the following example:
Unicode symbol \texttt{U+26A1} "High Voltage" and  \texttt{U+2607} "Lightning"
\setmainfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}
\[\text{\symbol{"26A1}\symbol{"2607}}\]
\end{document}
```

If you comment out the last package and the last two lines in the document, you may compile with PDFLaTeX as well. I just wanted to show the two unicode symbols I found for lightnings and how you could access them.

[image]

Or you use the package `fontawesome`:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\[\text{\faBolt}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. I did not know you could change their sizes and make them bold as well. Great tips. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }
\lightning
mathmode

\usepackage{ wasysym }
\lightning
textmode

\usepackage{ marvosym }
\Lightning
textmode
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete MWE for each of your suggestions?

Comment: This entry was actually more helpful than the others as it's simple and it works. It could be improved by including a PDF for illustration, though.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use `\textup`, not `\text` or `\mbox`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} %margin
\usepackage{ marvosym }

\newcommand\blitz{\textup{\Lightning}}

\begin{document}
\section*{The {\Lightning} Symbol in Math Mode is \(\blitz^{\blitz^\blitz}\)}'
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda\gamma \blitz_{\blitz_\blitz}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Marvosym sample]

If you want to use it as an operator, additionally wrap it in `\mathbin{\textup{\Lightning}}` or `\mathrel{\textup{\Lightning}}`, etc. If you do not want the symbol to appear bold in bold headers, use `\textnormal` instead of `\textup`.  (I don’t believe this does anything for `marvosym`, but it would for many other symbol fonts.)

If you use `\text`, the symbol will be formatter to match the surrounding text—for example, it will switch to italics if used in an italicized theorem statement.  If you use `\mbox`, it will not scale in superscripts or subscripts.

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you should use the ☇ (U+260 Lightning) or ⚡ (U+26A1 high voltage) Unicode symbols from a font that contains them, e.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola} % Clone of the New Century Schoolbook font used in fouriernc
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\textblitz{{\symbolfont\symbol{"26A1}}}
\newcommand\mathblitz{\textup{\textblitz}}

\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={3.5cm,3cm}, vmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}]{geometry} %margin

\begin{document}
\section*{The {\textblitz} Symbol in Math Mode is \(\mathblitz^{\mathblitz^\mathblitz}\) }
\[ \Lambda\gamma \mathblitz_{\mathblitz_\mathblitz}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Schola/DejaVu Sans sample]