# Set dpi of locally created font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex

I was looking for a lightning symbol and came across this post:

[The lightning symbol in an equation environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198462/the-lightning-symbol-in-an-equation-environment)

I liked the lightning symbol from the `ulsy` package (from the second answer) and tried to use it. The first problem was that texlive does not come with this package. So I downloaded it from CTAN and followed the instructions to create the `Uulsy.fd` and `ulsy.sty` files. (I am using the files locally only because I intend to integrate in my overleaf project, which as far as I know does not support installing custom fonts.)

My actual problem is, when I use it in my document I only get a low resolution of the lightning bolt, especially when I am increasing the size (e.g. with `scalebox` or `resizebox`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulsy}
\let\ulsyLightning\blitza

\begin{document}
        \resizebox{0.5\textheight}{!}{\ulsyLightning}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A few things I noticed: I tried different latex engines and get the same results with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`. However, by using just `latex` and then converting the `.dvi` file to `.pdf` with `dvipdf`, I get a lightning bolt with a much higher resolution. I noticed that `pdflatex`, as well as `lualatex` creating a file named `ulsy10.600pk` and latex `ulsy10.8000pk`. Since during the `pdf-/lualatex` I can see the message

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ulsy10
```

my assumption is that the 600pk/8000pk is related to the resolution of the created image which is used for the font.

[image]

So my question is, is it somehow possible to control the resolution and still using `pdf-/lualatex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that, for a bitmap font like ulsy, the resolution used by pdftex is defined by the variable `\pdfpkresolution`, which is set to 600 in the usual default configuration.  The resolution used by dvips and the wrapper script dvipdf is set by a line reading

```
D 8000
```

in the file `$TEXMF/dvips/config.pdf` if it is not specified by a command line argument such as `-D 8000`.  As another answer notes, there is a Type 1 version of the font that avoids these questions, but since it has been autotraced from Metafont output, the outlines are a bit crude.

The problem of low resolution partly arises from the fact that your TeX output is being scaled up at the Postscript level, and for a bitmap font, that means magnifying the existing pixels, rather than using more pixels.  Setting the resolution to 8000 dpi partially compensates for this, but a better solution is either to use an outline font, or to scale the font when it is loaded, using a TeX command like

```
\font\bigulsy=ulsy10 scaled 10000
```

or the equivalent in LaTeX, instead of scaling the PostScript.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to get the postscript version of the font (from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ps-type1/ulsy), put the pfa into `fonts/type1/public/ulsy/ulsy.pfa`, the map-file into `fonts/map`, run mktexlsr and activate the map-file with updmap  (or add a `\pdfmapline` command).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\pdfmapline{=ulsy10 ulsy < ulsy.pfa} %or activate the map file
\usepackage{ulsy}
\let\ulsyLightning\blitza

\begin{document}
        \resizebox{0.5\textheight}{!}{\ulsyLightning}
\end{document}
```

[image]